# Why do we put an electron in a potential well to derive the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I do understand the math behind and the "derivation". And I do understand why it is smart for our equations to put it in a potential well with infinite thick walls and a length.

What I don't get: why are we allowed to put an electron into a potential well? And why are we allowed to explain particles "in the wild" with that model?

TL;DR: Potential well gives us nice equations but why are we allowed to use that model?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you're actually asking, are you asking why we are allowed to use "infinite" potentials? "*Why are we allowed to put an electron into a potential well*" isn't really a clear question, at least not to me.

Comment: Who used potential wells to derive the Schrodinger equation? Great claims should come with great evidence. :)

Answer (score 2):

This derivation is usually in a first course of quantum mechanics. At this point, students learn how to do calculations with one particle. So rather than calculating how an electron and a nucleus interact, the nucleus is "hidden".

An electron is light enough that uncertainty in momentum and position matter. A proton is 1800 times heavier than an electron, and these uncertainties are much smaller. So the proton is approximated as a classical point charge.

In a fully classical problem, the electron would follow a trajectory and the force could be calculated at each point. But a quantum electron is described by a wave. There is no trajectory, just probabilities of finding it a various points. The nice thing about energy is that you don't need to know the trajectory to know how much energy the electron has if it happens to be at a point.

The Schrodinger equation is written in terms of energy. So the only property of the proton that matters is the potential. Or how much potential energy the electron has at each point.

The Schrodinger equation also works with other potential wells. All of these potential wells are regions where the electron has lower energy. Or equivalently, they are regions where the electron experiences an attractive force.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answer, this addresses

> What I don't get: why are we allowed to put an electron into a potential well?

Why questions in physics, sometimes after considerable mathematical perambulations, end up with the ultimate simple answer *because it fits the data* .

Physics is a discipline where mathematics is used to model existing data and, *important*, to predict future behaviors.

Schrodinger's equation is a sophisticated mathematical model that lead to the theory of Quantum Mechanics. It modeled the data of the hydrogen atom, given in the spectral series fitted with the first quantum mechanical model, the [Bohr model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html#c4).

So the answer to the first *why* is *because it fits the data*

> And why are we allowed to explain particles "in the wild" with that model?

Once the theory of Quantum Mechanics developed  it applies to modeling particles both in potential wells and in the *wild* . Quantum mechanics is the theory from which all matter descriptions emerge, even classical theories as known in the nineteenth century can be shown to emerge from QM models. It is the only [mathematical theory](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quacon.html) we have in mainstream physics to describe particles in the *wild* or in *cages.*